# Create my own warning message outside a function?

Tags: r, warnings

This should be simple based on posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858209/r-function-return-value-as-well-warning-message) but somehow I cannot get it to work. What is wrong with this example?

```
x<-1
y<-0
if(x>y){warning("careful, one is greater than zero!")}
```

It works with `stop()`:

```
if(x>y){stop("careful, one is greater than zero!")}
```

So either I'm making a simple syntax mistake or warning is not supposed to be used outside of functions?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It seems to work for me...

Comment: Maybe you haven't enabled displaying warnings?

Comment: The first one just returns nothing. The second displays a warning.

Comment: so for you, the first one actually returns one of those red warning messages in the console after you run the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with me. I'm using R 3.3.2.

I think a possibile solution to your problem is to check if warning messages are enabled in your session.
If you read **?options**, you'll notice that between the values returned by the function there is the warn value.

**From the reference:**
*warn:
sets the handling of warning messages. If warn is negative all warnings are ignored. If warn is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns. If 10 or fewer warnings were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how many were signalled. An object called last.warning is created and can be printed through the function warnings. If warn is one, warnings are printed as they occur. If warn is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors.*

So, if you have a negative value for warn, you won't see warning messages.
You can enable warning messages in the following way:

```
options(warn=1)
```

Try changing this and re-run your code.